# How to check if a mail item has the "Mark Complete" flag set using EWS API

Tags: c#, outlook, exchangewebservices

I am setting the  *mark complete* flag using EWS API for a given mail using the following code snippet:

```
 ExtendedPropertyDefinition epd_PidTagFlagStatus = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x1090, MapiPropertyType.Integer);
                item.SetExtendedProperty(epd_PidTagFlagStatus, 0x00000001);
```

Now, what is the method to check if a given mail item has this flag set?

**EDIT:** My intent is to filter out mails with the "Mark Complete Flag" set. I was able to solve this issue. I have provided an answer for others' reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking the mail extended properties *after* fetching them, we can specify a *Search filter* to filter out mails with such extended properties *while fetching the mails*. In my particular case, I was able to do this by using the following SearchFilter:

```
SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And,new SearchFilter.Not(new SearchFilter.Exists(new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x1090, MapiPropertyType.Integer))));
```